# Mechanism to provide browser and/or android keyboard with suggestions/list of items for autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I've got an asp.net page with a textbox loaded in an Android browser.

If you tap on the textbox a keyboard pops up.  As you begin typing suggestions are displayed by the keyboard.

Is there any way to have the keyboard use a custom list of suggestions?

Would that be a function of the browser, keyboard or OS?

Thank you.

Comment: Replace the text box with a dropdown.

Comment: I don't want a dropdown.  I want the Android keyboard to use my list of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the text box with your own Autocomplete text box, [like this one](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin).

If you want to control it at the Android level, you have to write your own Android app and use the [AutoComplete Widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).